# How can i take user input in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, user-input

```
import 'dart:io';
main()
{
  print('What is your name: ');
  String name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('Your age is = $name');
}
```

//I'm having this error when i'm taking user input in dart, Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.

Comment: Did you enabled null safety?

Comment: See https://dart.dev/null-safety/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using null safety. The error occurs because `stdin.readLineSync()` returns a `String?` but you assing it on `String name`. To fix it add a **?** or a **!**, but then make sure it is not null.

```
String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
```

```
String name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
```

Comment: you are welcome! Mark the question as resolved so others will know.

Comment: There's a big difference between `String? name = ...` and `String name = ...!`.  Don't just blindly pick one.  The latter will throw an exception if `readLineSync()` returns null, which can happen it immediately reaches EOF.